# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib' with tensorflow=2.0.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlg

I am using TensorFlow version=2.0.0
python version=3.7.3
I am trying to import the below statement

```
from tensorflow.contrib import rnn
```

And it gives error as
Module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'
How can I resolve this?

Comment: If you called a file `tensorflow.py`, pick a different name.

Answer (score 1):

from tensor flow

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/upgrade#compatibility_modules

> Because of TensorFlow 2.x module deprecations (for example, tf.flags and tf.contrib), some changes can not be worked around by switching to compat.v1. Upgrading this code may require using an additional library (for example, absl.flags) or switching to a package in tensorflow/addons.

and as describe in this thread

`tensorflow.contrib doesn't exist in 2.0.`

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31350#issuecomment-518749548

Comment: Can you please tell ..How can use those additional library with tensorflow 2.0

Comment: sorry  module deprecations means its gone in this version

Comment: is there any alternative to it? I have a repository which uses this module, and I have to upgrade it

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used older versions of tensorflow. Is this what you're looking for?

```py
from tensorflow.keras.layers import RNN
```

Info on contrib:
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate#a_note_on_slim_contriblayers

Comment: Using this gives error as ```AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core._api.v2.nn' has no attribute 'rnn_cell'```  Actually I am trying to  do something like this ```self.cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell```

Comment: Are you unable to import keras layers?

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LSTMCell

Comment: `import tensorflow.keras.layers as layers`
then...
`self.cell = layers.LSTMCell(units=units, activation=activation, dropout=dropout)`